# how to acces url in data using useParam in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router

so i have a json data with following format. when i am  trying to access the category using useParams its working but if i try to access data using use params i am only gettin "http" in the console..how to access the complete URL of data? .if i try to aces the category i am getting the correct info back but tryin to get complete url using useParams is giving me **data: "http:"** , i am tryin to access full URl not just http

what i have to do is ,get a menu of categories on home page,and then on clikcing on particular category iv to fetch data of particular category and list it in a new component.

```
[
{
"category": "all",
"data": "http://allevents.s3.amazonaws.com/tests/all.json"
},
{
"category": "music",
"data": "http://allevents.s3.amazonaws.com/tests/music.json"
},
{
"category": "business",
"data": "http://allevents.s3.amazonaws.com/tests/business.json"
},
{
"category": "sports",
"data": "http://allevents.s3.amazonaws.com/tests/sports.json"
},
{
"category": "workshops",
"data": "http://allevents.s3.amazonaws.com/tests/workshops.json"
}
]
```

so following is my app js

```
   import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import Listing from './components/Listing';

function App() {
  const [isLoading,setISLoading] = useState(true);
  const[events,setEvents] = useState()

  const getEvents = async()=>{
    const response = await fetch('https://allevents.s3.amazonaws.com/tests/categories.json');
    const eventsData =await response.json()
    
    setEvents(eventsData);
    setISLoading(false);
  }
  useEffect(()=>getEvents(),[]);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path ='/'>
           {isLoading?<h1>Loading...</h1>:<Menu events = {events}/>}
        </Route>
        <Route path = '/event/:data'>
          <Listing/>
        </Route>
   
      </Switch>
    </Router>


  );
}

export default App;
```

Menu.js component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Menu = ({events}) => {
    console.log(events);
    return (
        <div>
            {events.map((event)=>{
                return(  <div key={event.category}>
                    <Link to = {`/event/${event.data}`}><h3>{event.category.toUpperCase()}</h3></Link>
                    
                </div>)
            })}
        </div>
    )

   

    
}

export default Menu
```

and listing Component

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

const Listing = ({match}) => {
    console.log(useParams())
   
    return (
        <div>
         hi
         
        </div>
    )
}

export default Listing
```

[not getting the full link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izWhE.png)

Comment: Could you provide more code where you want to get data?

Comment: i have edited the question to provide all the code of app js and two components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your path in `Listing` you can write it like this:

```
const Listing = () => {
  const location = useLocation(); // import from "react-router-dom";
  console.log("location.pathname", location.pathname);

  return <div>hi</div>;
};
```

Comment: thank you for letting me know about useLocation , but i am confused tht my useParams is working very well when i am trying to access category but is truncating the data to just "http:" why am i not getting the whole link using useParams

Comment: I dont see where else you are using `useParams` ?

Comment: inmenus .js if i replace <Link to = {`/event/${event.data}`}><h3>{event.category.toUpperCase()}</h3></Link> **WITH**  <Link to = {`/event/${event.category}`}><h3>{event.category.toUpperCase()}</h3></Link> i am getting the correct information using useParams(),

Comment: It comes from `events` array not from useParam() hook. You can console.log it there. const params = useParams();
  console.log(`params`, params); it is empty object. {}

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/izWhE.png  does this pic clarifies my query a bit more?

Comment: i have to use useLocation instead of useParams?or am i using useParams in wrong way?

Comment: if useLocation is working why you should use anything else ? useParams returns an object of key/value pairs of URL parameters

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable input and being patient with me